# Assign return value of function to object property in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, object

```js
export default class Leaderboard extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.numLeaders = 10;
    this.topPlayers = populateLeaderboard(this.numLeaders);
    this.state = {
      tableHead: ['', 'Name', 'Age', 'School', 'Points'],
      //Trying to assign leaders array to tableTitle
      tableTitle: (function(this.numLeaders) {
        let leaders = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < numLeaders; i++) {
          leader.push(i);
        }
        return leaders;
      }())     
   
    };
  }
```

So I'm trying to generate an array within a function and then assign it as a return value to an object property. I'm not sure if I'm messing up with Javascript or React, I don't have a ton of practice with Javascript objects.

Comment: woah, this is a bit confusing as what you want to actually achieve. `tableTitle` is obviously where the issue is

Comment: I'm trying to generate an array of indicies based on the number of leaders, and assign it to tableTitle

Comment: the answer below should do you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it in your way, here it is:

```
this.state = {
    tableHead: ["", "Name", "Age", "School", "Points"],
    tableTitle: (() => {
      const leaders = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < this.numLeaders; i++) {
        leaders.push(i);
      }
      return leaders;
    })(),
  };
}
```

A working example.

```js
const state = {
  tableTitle: (() => {
        const leaders = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          leaders.push(i);
        }
        return leaders;
      })(),
};

console.log(state.tableTitle);
```

I skipped the argument part here since you can already reach `numleaders`. Why do you need an argument?

Also, I used an arrow function above to avoid binding `this`. If you stick to your version don't forget to bind it:

```
this.state = {
  tableHead: ["", "Name", "Age", "School", "Points"],
  tableTitle: function () {
    const leaders = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.numLeaders; i++) {
      leaders.push(i);
    }
    return leaders;
  }.bind(this)(),
};
```

Or, if you really want to stick to your original-original version :) you can try this one:

```
this.state = {
  tableTitle: (function (numLeaders) {
    const leaders = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numLeaders; i++) {
      leaders.push(i);
    }
    return leaders;
  }(this.numLeaders)),
};
```

You are passing the argument then getting it back. No need to bind `this` here since you are not using `this.numLeaders` in your function.

Here is an alternative with some [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys).

```
this.state = {
  tableHead: ["", "Name", "Age", "School", "Points"],
  tableTitle: [...Array(this.numLeaders).keys()],
};
```

A working example:

```js
const state = {
  tableTitle: [...Array(10).keys()],
};

console.log(state.tableTitle);
```

But, if this data is not dynamic maybe the `state` is not a suitable place for it.

Comment: A very comprehensive answer, thanks.